# Why can't I place a node under another node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I trying to place a node under another node, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,shadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,automata}    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                        semithick]
            \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=black,draw=none,text=white]

            \node[state] (A_1)                      {Sunny};
            \node[state] (B_1) [below of = A_1]     {Cloudy};
            \node[state] (C_1) [below of = B_1]     {Rainy};

            \node[state] (A_2) [right of = A_1]     {Sunny};
            \node[state] (B_2) [right of = B_1]     {Cloudy};
            \node[state] (C_2) [right of = C_1]     {Rainy};

            \node[state] (A_3) [right of = A_2]     {Sunny};
            \node[state] (B_3) [right of = B_2]     {Cloudy};
            \node[state] (C_3) [right of = C_2]     {Rainy};

            \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=blue,draw=none,text=white]

            \node[state] (O1) [below of = A_3]      {dry};
            %\node[state] (O2) [right of = O1]      {damp};        
            %\node[state] (O3) [right of = O2]      {soggy};

            \path  (A_1) edge   node {}  (A_2)
                   (A_1) edge   node {}  (B_2)
                   (A_1) edge   node {}  (C_2)

                   (B_1) edge   node {}  (A_2)
                   (B_1) edge   node {}  (B_2)
                   (B_1) edge   node {}  (C_2)

                   (C_1) edge   node {}  (A_2)
                   (C_1) edge   node {}  (B_2)
                   (C_1) edge   node {}  (C_2)

                   (A_2) edge   node {}  (A_3)
                   (A_2) edge   node {}  (B_3)
                   (A_2) edge   node {}  (C_3)

                   (B_2) edge   node {}  (A_3)
                   (B_2) edge   node {}  (B_3)
                   (B_2) edge   node {}  (C_3)

                   (C_2) edge   node {}  (A_3)
                   (C_2) edge   node {}  (B_3)
                   (C_2) edge   node {}  (C_3);


        \end{tikzpicture}        
        \caption{Example of Markov chain}
        %\label{fig:ex-markov}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to place

```
\node[state] (O1) [below of =of A_3]      {dry};
```

But somehow is the state not placed under A_3, but on C_2 instead.

[image]

This is how it looks like, and the red line shows where i want it to be.
Not the exact distance but just below A_3, using the fixed distance.

Comment: What's the second of?

Comment: @TeXnician is  right. Without the second "of" it works. Use `\node[state] (O1) [below of = A_3]     {dry};`

Comment: The error message says `Package pgf Error: No shape named of A_3 is known.`, and if you read it carefully, you'll see that TikZ looks for a node called `of A_3`, which clearly isn't what you meant, and is a hint at what's wrong.

Comment: @TeXnician I  guess it might have been a typo, but it is still positioned incorrectly.. it should be below A_3, but places on C_2 node...

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I just removed the second of, but didn't notice any error message before..

Comment: @Bobyandbob I guess it might have been a typo, but it is still positioned incorrectly.. it should be below A_3, but places on C_2 node...

Comment: If you use the version with two `of`s on ShareLaTeX, you should see something like http://imgur.com/a/ppWue over the preview -- note the red box with the number 1. If you click that number, you will see the error I mentioned.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "does not go there" can you explain where you are expecting the node to be placed, and where it is placed instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the position of the red line, you clearly want

```
below of=C_1
```

rather than

```
below of=A_3
```

Otherwise, the node will be placed below `A_3` i.e. on top of `B_3`.

You seem to be under the impression that your nodes are arranged like this:

```
A_1 B_1 C_1
A_2 B_2 C_2
A_3 B_3 C_3
```

but you have drawn them in this way:

```
A_1 A_2 A_3
B_1 B_2 B_3
C_1 C_2 C_3
```

Comment: ahh...  Yep.. That was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the TikZ manual "17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options".
The keys `below of`, `above of` etc, have been deprecated in favour of the more flexible `below`, `above` etc that are available with the `positioning` tikz library.

As an example, you can write `[below=of A_3]` and even `[below=2 of A_3]` to specify a distance.

Note that, unless you specify the `on grid` option, the distance between the nodes will be the length of the space between them, not the distance between their centers.

**EDIT**: After reading the comments I realised the problem may be a misinterpretation of the effect of the option `below`:
the effect of `below=of A` is to place the node below `A` with a distance between their edges of `1` (the exact measure of which depends on scaling etc but defaults to 1cm).
Now, it seems you are expecting `dry` to be placed below `A` but very close to it.
That is what would have happened with a `label=below:dry` style: `\node[state] (A_3) [right=of A_2,label={[state]below:dry}] {Sunny};`.
You can also specify a distance, try `below=.1 of A`.
In case this is not the problem, try being more specific and report exactly the nature of the issue (i.e. what does "does not like the usage of below" mean? Do you get an error?)

Comment: +1, that's exactly what I wanted to add. @J.Down see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9391/101651!

Comment: I just tried... i am using share latex, and it doesn't like the usage of below and above.

Comment: @J.Down Did you add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes

Comment: @J.Down I've just put you mwe into ShareLaTeX, added `positioning` and \usepackage{float}, changed all the `of =` with `= of` and it works perfectly. (BTW, you've loaded `tikz` twice and probably you don't need a float if your option is `H`...).